# Using Regex to find repeating groups in phone numbers

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to use regex to search for obviously false phone numbers that have the same digit repeating. The numbers are all formatted and stored as follows:

(111)111-1111

I'm not able to alter the text in any way.

I've tried modifying a few of the regex lines I've seen such as: 
    ^([0-9])\1{2}.\1{3}.\1{4}$
which was for finding repeating digits with a period in between the numbers. However, I haven't figured out how to get around the first character as a parenthesis.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try adding the parentheses to this regex?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding a [(] in a few spots, but that changes the first group from 111 to (111, which is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Adding `\(` at the left side will look for the optional open parenthesis, and adding `\)` at the end will look for the optional closing parenthesis. Of course, then you'll have to add either a positive lookahead at the opening paren to make sure the closing one is there, or a positive lookbehind at the closing one to make sure the opening one is there...

Comment: have you tried using a literal "(" and ")" in your regex by escaping it? so a regex for `111` becomes `\(111\)` for a simple example

Comment: Also, I recommend http://regexr.com to test and play with your regexes and learn.

Comment: @Ken: whoah – just tried it and got lost in lookaheads and look behinds – also tried with `(?(x)` IF. Care to give it an attempt? :)

Comment: Nope. :-) That's why I posted a comment and not an answer. I take a different approach; I strip all formatting first (removing `()-` and spaces) and validate what's left. It's much easier. It also means users can omit the formatting, and if needed for display purposes I have a regex that will properly format it for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand the purpose of the `.` Dot Operator. It is not to match a period, it matches *anything*. In that (quite badly) regex, it serves only to skip the `-` – and because it matches anything, it will also match something like `11121113111`.

Use this regexp instead:

```
^\(?([0-9])\1{2}\)?\1{3}-?\1{4}$
```

This checks for parentheses around the first group, optionally so it will still work without; and specifically checks for the presence of a dash between the second and third group of digits, also optionally.

Comment: This worked extremely well, thank you for the clarifiction on the dot operator as well!